# How do you develop games for Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I want to try developing a game for Google+. Does anyone know how these are developed? Is there a resource somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you will find some information:

- [Games in Google+: fun that fits your schedule](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/games-in-google-fun-that-fits-your.html)

> If you’re a developer interested in building games for Google+, you
>   can learn more on our new [Google+ developer blog](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2011/08/stepping-onto-google-platform.html).

- [Stepping Onto the Google+ Platform](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2011/08/stepping-onto-google-platform.html)

> If you’re a developer interested in building for the Google+ platform,
>   **[let us know](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/)** and we’ll contact you when we have something for you to
>   preview. Just remember, like the [rest of the Google+ project](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/introducing-google-project-real-life.html) this is
>   only the beginning, so stay tuned.
>
> Follow the conversation [here](https://plus.google.com/110563351377427897709/posts/AD9G1MfAFnj) on Google+.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to wait:

- http://www.google.com/support/+/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1334138&answer=1334269

> ...Your email address will be added to a Google group so we can easily keep you posted.

Comment: @UpTheCreek:  The fact cited by that link was time-sensitive and is possibly no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is an official API for google plus just yet - I think it will be coming soon though. have a read of this [post](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/07/12/google-plus-api-is-it-intentionally-late/)

Answer (score 0):

Deducing from the existing games on Google+ Games it seems that you start creating one using Flash or JavaScript.  I believe anything that works on modern browsers should also work on Google+ with little tweak.  I'm not waiting for API to come out to develop a game. I think API would merely open up the pipeline to pull/push data onto Google+ platform.